# How can I bind GeoJSON data to parameters in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, geojson, system.text.json

In GeoJSON the same attribute `coordinates` can be an array or array of arrays.

How can I define the same attribute name but different types for the same json object?

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("coordinates")]
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("coordinates")]
    public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

coordinates can be 4d or 3d, how can I handle this variability?

example:

```
{
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    [
                        51.263632,
                        60.962938
                    ],
                    [
                        30.884274,
                        20.065517
                    ],
                    [
                        68.832044,
                        14.362602
                    ],
                    [
                        51.263632,
                        60.962938
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                [
                    43.182162,
                    64.042209
                ],
                [
                    14.721334,
                    22.358269
                ],
                [
                    51.263632,
                    17.738761
                ],
                [
                    43.182162,
                    64.042209
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [
                    55.831419,
                    51.446822
                ],
                [
                    65.66973,
                    20.065517
                ],
                [
                    97.64424,
                    37.509124
                ],
                [
                    55.831419,
                    51.446822
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

My action is

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult<Geometry> Create(Geometry layer)
{
    _layerService.Create(layer);
    
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: It may not be possible to do this because when a class is serialized it will be a form of key and value and if key are same value gets overridden.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does the JSON string or schema look like? What you posted is what you assume the solution would look like. There are *standardized* ways of representing spatial data in JSON. No need to invent your own

Comment: Are you trying to parse GeoJSON by hand?

Comment: I think this class will not compile. Independent of JSON.

Comment: @Klamsi yes, that is the question

Comment: @XLVII that looks like GeoJSON. There are several [NuGet packages that can parse GeoJSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=geojson), some with over 1M downloads. These work with JSON.NET though. Is your real question how to parse GeoJSON using System.Text.Json in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags. This question isn't related to ASP.NET Core (a web framework).

Comment: @Llama why did you assume that? Why do you assume the question *isn't* about deserializing GeoJSON in an ASP.NET Core application? Most GeoJSON packages use JSON.NET, so ASP.NET Core would require special treatment

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it's all about GeoJSON. I intuitively thought I was very close to the solution, can't I just make a few changes to the class I'm showing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because OP has provided nothing to tie it to ASP.NET Core beyond the tag. And even if it does pertain to System.Text.Json then they can add the System.Text.Json tag and it would be infinitely more relevant than the ASP.NET Core tag would ever be for this question. That's especially true if you consider that even in recent versions of ASP.NET Core, you can still use the JSON.NET serializer if you want to - it's just not the default out of the box anymore.

Comment: @Llama then wait before assuming. There are a ton of packages for JSON.NET. Very few for STJ. And enabling GeoJSON binding in ASP.NET Core is another matter entirely. By removing the tags you removed the most important part of the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not going to apologise for removing misued tags. There is a tag for GeoJSON and there is a tag for System.Text.Json. ASP.NET Core is tangential to the question at best. Just because you made the jump from ASP.NET Core to "probably a question about System.Text.Json" doesn't mean that the ASP.NET Core tag is the correct one to use. If there is something more complicated re plumbing it into their ASP.NET Core application (thus making the tag relevant), then OP should detail that in their question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's about automatic binding, it will only be used as an argument in get-post operations

Comment: @XLVII GeoJSON4STJ  handles this as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to roll your own classes. This isn't something that can be done in a single step, and the classes you'll end up won't be easy to use for spatial scenarios. It's better to use common spatial classes and a library that can serialize them.

Even if you roll your own, it would be *a lot* easier to create custom JSON converters that map your Spatial classes to GeoJSON.

NetTopologySuite, the almost-de-facto standard for spatial data in .NET Core, has published the [NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ/) package that serializes NTS classes to GeoJSON using System.Text.Json. At 84K downloads it's not as popular as the 1.4M downloads of [NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/) that uses JSON.NET, but it does the job.

The [repo landing page](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/tree/develop) shows how to use `GeoJSON4STJ` to bind GeoJSON payloads to `Geometry` parameters in classes, by adding a custom converter :

```
services.AddControllers()
  .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(
            new NetTopologySuite.IO.Converters.GeoJsonConverterFactory());
  });
```

The NTS classes are used by [EF Core itself for Spatial data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) so it's a great idea to use *these* instead of creating new classes.

The landing page shows [how to (de)serialize JSON text](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/tree/develop#geojson-usage) too:

```
var geoJson = "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[0.0,0.0]}";
Geometry geometry;

var serializer = GeoJsonSerializer.Create();
using var stringReader = new StringReader(geoJson);
using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);

var geometry = serializer.Deserialize<Geometry>(jsonReader);
```

and

```
var geometry = new Point(0, 0);

var serializer = GeoJsonSerializer.Create();
using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);

serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, geometry);
var geoJson = stringWriter.ToString();
```

The [GeoJsonSerializer.Create()](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/blob/develop/src/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/GeoJsonSerializer.cs#L42) method just creates a new `JsonSerializer` with the `GeoJSON` converter:

```
    public new static JsonSerializer Create()
    {
        return CreateDefault();
    }

    public new static JsonSerializer CreateDefault()
    {
        var s = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
        s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        AddGeoJsonConverters(s, Wgs84Factory, 2, false, null);
        return s;
    }
```

**Creating your own**

If you decide to create your own GeoJSON converters, a *great* place to start would be to [check the GeoJSON4STJ converters](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/tree/develop/src/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/Converters). There's not just one converter, there's a different converter for each type, or rather, category of types. There are different converters for coordinates, arrays and single features. This makes serializing a *lot* easier and faster. Once you read the `type` you know what to do with the other attributes of an object.

Another option is to load the entire JSON string as a JsonDocument and use a Visitor to go over all nodes and parse them according to their `type`. That's slower and uses more memory as the JsonDocument is essentially a copy of the source data.